# Like buttons shows wrong count on secure connection

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-like

I have an application with some Facebook Like buttons on every page. When we open the page via insecure connection 
( http://apps.facebook.com/olinezza_photos/index/index/creator/all/order/likes/page/1 ), the like buttons show the right count (checked in link_stat FQL table). But when we open the application via secure connection ( https://apps.facebook.com/olinezza_photos/index/index/creator/all/order/likes/page/1 ), the button counts are wrong - they show smaller numbers. Then I refreshed every single like link ( the debugger tool with curl requests) - one time for the http version and one for the https one. So, that worked and the https like buttons were showing the right count... only for 24 hours (or maybe a little more), when the problem appeared again - in https connections the same like buttons were showing wrong button count again (for example, the real count is 600, https like buttons show 4. After a refresh they show the real 600 and after 24 hours - 4 again). So, what I do at the moment is refreshing the links every day (that means that when you open the links, the button count may be right, but the problem is not resolved - I have 4000 links, that means 8000 requests to Facebook every day). I hope there's a different way to fix it - maybe from Facebook side.

Answer (score 0):

Since full URL's are different (the only difference being http and https), their like/share counts are also different. We have experienced the same problem when we switched to lowercase URLs.

As a solution, in the like button html code we used our old URLs to preserve like count and it worked. So you may use the URL with http in both http and https versions of the page. I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I mentioned in the question above, that after refreshing like button counts are OK. That's why they both lead to one place, where in the meta tag og:url there is only one link - the http version. So, in the FQL table link_stat we have ONE row about this link, not two. That means the button counts must be equal.

Comment: In our website, our og:url and href of our like button are different. The one that counts for us is the like button href -> og:url is somehow ignored.

Comment: By the way, I am receiving nine "Access is denied" javascript errors inside jquery-1.4.2 - same number as Like button count. Try setting href attribute to http version and see what happens. In our website it worked out.

Comment: I also have "Access is denied" javascript errors sometimes, but not every time. I'll try the trick with the href attribute, but that doesn't mean that this Facebook bug doesn't have to be fixed...